# Parse live query not working?

Tags: javascript, parse-platform

I tried setting up parse live query, but for some reason it returns no results.

I can pull data from it, so I know the server and db are running fine.

The 'open' connection works when I run on localhost, but even then, the subscription events are never called.

**Client**

```
var Parse = require('parse/node');

Parse.initialize("key", "", "pass");
Parse.serverURL = parseServer;
Parse.liveQueryServerURL = 'ws://localhost:1337/';


let query = new Parse.Query('groups');
query.equalTo('name', 'name');
let subscription = query.subscribe();


subscription.on('update', (people) => {
    console.log("YEAY");
  // console.log(people.get('score')); // This should output 100
});

subscription.on('open', () => {
    console.log('subscription opened');
});
```

**Server**

```
var app = new ParseServer({
startLiveQueryServer: true,
  liveQuery: {
    classNames: ["groups", "comments"] // List of classes to support for query subscriptions
  },
..}

var port = process.env.PORT || 1337;
var httpServer = require('http').createServer(app);
httpServer.listen(port, function() {
    console.log('parse-server-example running on port ' + port + '.');
});

// This will enable the Live Query real-time server
var parseLiveQueryServer = ParseServer.createLiveQueryServer(httpServer);
```

Comment: odd select expression : query.equalTo('name', 'name');   u might try using a 2nd client to submit a valid query ( normal async response) to check whether a normal client gets a result set sz > 0

Comment: haha yeah. any idea though why this isn't working? I'm running on elastic beanstalk. I even added in the nginx file in my .ebextension https://www.nginx.com/blog/websocket-nginx/

Comment: @RobertRowntree yeah I can confirm normal queries work. just subscriptions aren't called :/

Comment: What if `let` is causing scope issues for subscriptions. Where events are only called in `Client.js` or does that not matter?

Comment: @Alex took out, still didn't work :/

Answer (score 0):

You can try changing this

```
let subscription = query.subscribe();
```

to this

```
let subscription = await query.subscribe();
```

Hope it helps.

Comment: did you found any solution to this?